# Google Contacts API retrieve group name for each contact

Tags: php, arrays, google-api-php-client

How can I retrieve the name of the group a contact belongs to?
This is how google stores the group information:

```
<gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted="false" href="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/{my_email address}/base/1fklk0eb8b87ad92"/>
```

I am building an autocomplete list, but since the user knows only "family" and not the group id, it is impossible to downsize the list with the group name.

EDIT: Step closer but new problem [relationship between 2 arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957467/relationship-between-2-arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

Store all the groups in an array Groups []:
request url:
`https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default/full`

Store all the contacts in an array Contacts[]:
request url:
`https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full`

Combine this 2 arrays ([relationship between 2 arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957467/relationship-between-2-arrays))

```
foreach($contacts as &$contact) {
                  // ^ reference
    foreach($groups as $group) {
        if($contact['group'] == $group['value']) {
            $contact['group'] = $group['name'];
        }
    }
}
```