# relationship between 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with all contacts and I have an array with all groups.
How can I replace `http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/j**/base/3166d58a8c**25` with the group name `YouTube` in the contact array?
Since Google Contacts API v3 does store the group name as an id, I want to replace this id with the name of the group.

E.g.

Array groups:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(87) "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/**/base/***b87ad92"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Family"
    ["label"]=>
    string(4) "Family"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(87) "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/j**/base/3166d58a8c**25"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "YouTube"
    ["label"]=>
    string(7) "YouTube"
  }
}
```

Array Contacts:

```
array(250) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(15) "X Y"
    ["name"]=>
    string(15) "X Y"
    ["email"]=>
    string(25) "blabla@gmail.com"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(10) "044564"
    ["group"]=>
    string(87) "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/j**/base/3166d58a8c**25"
    ["phonework"]=>
    string(10) "0479//804"
    ["address"]=>
    string(28) "55222 City"
    ["label"]=>
    string(15) "Bla"
      }
  ......
    }
```

Final output would be:

```
array(250) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["value"]=>
    string(15) "X Y"
    ["name"]=>
    string(15) "X Y"
    ["email"]=>
    string(25) "blabla@gmail.com"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(10) "044564"
    ["group"]=>
    string(87) "YouTube"
    ["phonework"]=>
    string(10) "0479//804"
    ["address"]=>
    string(28) "55222 City"
    ["label"]=>
    string(15) "Bla"
      }
  ......
    }
```

Comment: so whats the final output?

Comment: I've added the desired output in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a nested loop. Loop the contacts first (which will be overwritten), then inside it the groups. Inside the inner loop, just make an equality comparison:

```
foreach($contacts as &$contact) {
                  // ^ reference
    foreach($groups as $group) {
        if($contact['group'] == $group['value']) {
            $contact['group'] = $group['name'];
        }
    }
}
```